# How to create SQL query in Codiginator Model insensitive queries - SQL LIKE queries

Tags: php, mysql

I designed an app in Codeignitor, here I search enquiry based on contact person name, company name, email id, mobile no. I am using CI ORM Statements to perform database queries - does anyone have an idea how I can ignore case in these columns, so all the columns in capital or small letter there is no impact.

Here is my modal function for search the query:

```
public function search1($from1, $to1, $q)
{
    if(empty($q))
    {
        $this->db->where("enq_date >=",$from1);
        $this->db->where("enq_date <=",$to1);
        return $this->db->get('enq_capture')->result();
    }
    else
    {       
        $where = array('enq_date>=' => $from1, 'enq_date <=' => $to1);                      
        $query=$this->db->select('*')
                    ->from('enq_capture')
                    ->where($where)
                    ->like('company_name',$q)
                    ->or_like('c_person',$q)
                    //->or_like('email',$q)
                    ->get();

        //print_r($query);
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

And here is my controller function:

```
public function search1()
{
    $data['user_data']=$this->is_logged_in();
    $q=$this->input->post('searchid');
    $from1=$this->input->post('from1');
    $to1=$this->input->post('to1');
    $data['search_data']=$this->Enquiry_model->search1($from1,$to1,$q);
    $this->load->view('admin1/enquiry/search_enquiry1',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use LOWER() function

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM enq_capture WHERE enq_date >= '{$from1}' AND enq_date <= '{$to1}' AND (LOWER(company_name) LIKE '%{$qLower}%' OR LOWER(c_person) LIKE '%{$qLower}%')");
return $query->result();
```

Comment: to check query `echo $this->db->last_query();`

Comment: when i comment any one line given below then result is fine and accurate but when i check both by company name or by person name it return wrong result                                                                                 
          ->like('LOWER(company_name)', strtolower($q))     
        ->or_like('LOWER(c_person)', strtolower($q))

Comment: Please echo the query with both check, so I can understand more.

Comment: how to echo query in ci

Comment: In controller under the `$data['search_data']=$this->Enquiry_model->search1($from1,$to1,$q);`  add line as `echo $this->db->last_query();`

Comment: when i uncomment both the line it return SELECT * FROM `enq_capture` WHERE `enq_date` >= '2017-06-05' AND `enq_date` <= '2017-06-05' AND LOWER(company_name) LIKE '%a%' ESCAPE '!' OR LOWER(c_person) LIKE '%a%' ESCAPE '!'

Comment: when i comment second row it return SELECT * FROM `enq_capture` WHERE `enq_date` >= '2017-06-05' AND `enq_date` <= '2017-06-05' AND LOWER(company_name) LIKE '%ra%' ESCAPE '!' and exact result

Comment: Ok good, so query seems fine, now what you exactly want for your result
**1.** company_name LIKE '%a%'  **OR** c_person LIKE '%a%' 
**2.** company_name LIKE '%a%'  **AND** c_person LIKE '%a%'

Comment: Or give me simple query, I will make it suitable for CI

Comment: actually i am getting specific date range from the user from and to and search the enquiry in this specific range in first case it check in between specific rnage but in second case when i uncomment both line then it is not following the date range it simply return the result

Comment: i update the code and my ajax function returning the fail

Comment: See the simplest way to get result

Comment: $q1=strtolower($q);
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM enq_capture WHERE enq_date >= '{$from1}' AND enq_date <= '{$to1}' AND (LOWER(company_name) LIKE '%{$q1}%' OR LOWER(c_person) LIKE '%{$q1}%')");
return $query->result();        This Code is Working For Me  Thanks For Help